# Run development server using django exe

Tags: django, localhost, exe, django-runserver

I have been trying to run the exe file(created using pyInstaller) of my Django project on the development server so that I can verify whether it is working properly or not. Tried some commands and also asked Chatgpt but could find any suitable solution.

The commands that I have tried:
**Input:**

```
manage.exe runserver
```

**Response:**

```
File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
File "manage.py", line 10, in main
File "django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
File "django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
File "django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
File "django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 74, in execute
File "django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
File "django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 111, in handle
File "django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in run
File "django\utils\autoreload.py", line 682, in run_with_reloader
File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_django.py", line 23, in _restart_with_reloader
File "django\utils\autoreload.py", line 272, in restart_with_reloader
File "django\utils\autoreload.py", line 259, in get_child_arguments
RuntimeError: Script runserver does not exist.
[19796] Failed to execute script 'manage' due to unhandled exception!
```

**Input:**

```
manage.exe runserver 127.0.01:8000 (Derived after running "manage.exe help runserver")
```

**Response:**
Same as above

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/72838426/10951070